# Split a Value in a Column with Right Function in SSIS

Tags: etl, ssis

I need an urgent help from you guys, the thing i have a column which represent the full name of a user , now i want to split it into first and last name.

The format of the Full name is "World, hello", now the first name here is hello and last name is world.

I am using Derived Column(SSIS) and using Right Function for First Name and substring function for last name, but the result of these seems to be blank, this where even i am blank. :)

Comment: can you show us the expression you are using in the derived column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working for me. In general, you should provide more detail in your questions on places such as this to help others recreate and troubleshoot your issue. You did not specify whether we needed to address NULLs in this field nor do I know how you'd want to interpret it so there is room for improvement on this answer.

I started with a simple OLE DB Source and hard coded a query of "SELECT 'World, Hello' AS Name".

I created 2 Derived Column Tasks. The first one adds a column to Data Flow called FirstCommaPosition. The formula I used is `FINDSTRING(Name,",", 1)` If NAME is NULLable, then we will need to test for nullability prior to calling the FINDSTRING function. You'll then need to determine how you will want to store the split data in the case of NULLs. I would assume both first and last are should be NULLed but I don't *know* that.

There are two reasons for doing this in separate steps. The first is performance. As counter-intuitive as it sounds, doing less in a derived column results in better performance because the SSIS engine can better parallelize the operations. The other is more simple - I will need to use this value to make the first and last name split so it will be easier and less maintenance to reference a column than to copy paste a formula.

The second Derived Column is going to actually perform the split.

My FirstNameUnicode column uses this formula `(FirstCommaPosition > 0) ? RTRIM(LTRIM(RIGHT(Name,FirstCommaPosition))) : ""`  That says "If we found a comma in the preceding step, then slice out everything from the comma's position to the end of the string and apply trim operations. If we didn't find a comma, then just return a blank string. The default string type for expressions will be the Unicode (DT_WSTR) so if that is not your need, you will need to cast the resultant into the correct string codepage (DT_STR)

My LastNameUnicode column uses this formula `(FirstCommaPosition > 0) ? SUBSTRING(Name,1,FirstCommaPosition -1) : ""` Similar logic as above except now I use the SUBSTRING operation instead of RIGHT. Users of the 2012 release of SSIS and beyond, rejoice fo you can use the LEFT function instead of SUBSTRING. Also note that you will need to back off 1 position to remove the comma.

[image]