# Getting the string in between characters using SSIS

Tags: string, ssis, substring, concatenation

I read up on Left, Right, Substring, CharIndex, but wasn't able to implement the solution correctly. I want to convert:

1;#Jackson, Michael  (X) 
To: 
Jackson, Michael

Basically, I want to remove 1;# from the left and spaces and (X) after the name ends. I cannot use any hardcoded numbers, since the length of first and last name could vary. Can you please assist? I want to do this using the Derived Column component in SSIS.

Comment: Is the leading pattern always digit-semicolon-sharp or does it vary? Is the trailing pattern always openparen-X-closeparen?

Comment: Likely duplicates [ex1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33023858/181965) [ex2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31122657/181965) [ex3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15176398/181965)

Comment: @billinkc: Yes the leading pattern is always digit(s)-semicolon-sharp. The trailing pattern is always openparen-X-closeparen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of possible solutions depending on your needs.

T-SQL

```
DECLARE @text varchar(100) = '1;#Jackson, Michael (X)', @clean_text varchar(100)
SELECT @clean_text = RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@text, CHARINDEX('#', @text) + LEN('#'), 
                CHARINDEX('(X)', @text, CHARINDEX('#', @text)) - (CHARINDEX('#', @text) + LEN('#'))))
SELECT @clean_text
```

C#

```
string text = "1;#Jackson, Michael (X)", clean_text = "", hash = "#", x = "(";
clean_text = text.Substring(text.IndexOf(char.Parse(hash)) + hash.Length,
        text.IndexOf(char.Parse(x), text.IndexOf(char.Parse(hash))) - (text.IndexOf(char.Parse(hash)) + hash.Length)).Trim();
Console.WriteLine(clean_text);
```

SSIS

```
RTRIM(SUBSTRING(CreatedBy, FINDSTRING(CreatedBy, "#", 1) + LEN("#"), FINDSTRING(CreatedBy, "(X)", 1) - (FINDSTRING(CreatedBy, "#", 1) + LEN("#"))))
```

SSIS with or without (X)

```
FINDSTRING(CreatedBy,"(X)",1) > 0 ? RTRIM(SUBSTRING(CreatedBy,FINDSTRING(CreatedBy,"#",1) + LEN("#"),FINDSTRING(CreatedBy,"(X)",1) - (FINDSTRING(CreatedBy,"#",1) + LEN("#")))) : RTRIM(SUBSTRING(CreatedBy,FINDSTRING(CreatedBy,"#",1) + LEN("#"), LEN(CreatedBy)+1 - (FINDSTRING(CreatedBy,"#",1) + LEN("#"))))
```

Comment: Thanks R. Richards. Do you have the solution using the Derived Column in SSIS?

Comment: I have added that, but I don't know how to test it without a bunch of effort. You may have to play around with the formula.

Comment: Thx, it worked. At least the expression is now being accepted. However, I am getting this cryptic error message:Error: 0xC0209029 at Data Flow Task, Derived Column [16]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Derived Column" failed because error code 0xC0049067 occurred, and the error row disposition on "Derived Column.Inputs[Derived Column Input].Columns[Copy of Created By]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component. If I configure the error output to 'Ignore Error', NULLs are written instead of the transformed value.

Comment: I have updated my SSIS answer. I have the parameter switched around. I tested this successfully with some mock data.

Comment: Apparently the (X) at the end only appears for some names. So, how to handle if the (X) is not present? (I know billinkc asked this Q earlier; but just found out it could happen).

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer; either one, since they both seemed to work. Thanks!

Comment: The one marked as 'SSIS with or without (X)' is the best solution. The problem with ichauvin's answer is, it assumed 1 is always the first digit.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I am not being clear. Red this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> Basically, I want to remove 1;# from the left and spaces and (X) after the name ends...I want to do this using the Derived Column component in SSIS

Expression in Derived Column Transformation from source to destination:

REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Sample,"1",""),";",""),"#",""),"(X)","")," ","")

From: 1;#Jackson, Michael (X)

To: Jackson,MichaelTo:Jackson,Michael