# SSIS Derived Column - Text in Numeric Field is not converting

Tags: sql-server, ssis, derived-column

I'm importing thousands of csv files into an SQL DB.  They each have two columns:  Date and Value.  In some of the files, the value column contains simply a period (ex:  ".").  I've tried to create a derived column that will handle any cell that contains a period with the following code:

```
FINDSTRING((DT_WSTR,1)[VALUE],".",1) != 0 ? NULL(DT_R8) : [VALUE]
```

But, when the package runs it gets the following error when it reaches the cell with the period in it:

```
The data conversion for column "VALUE" returned status value 2 and status text 
"The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data".
```

I'm guessing there might be an escape character that I'm missing in my FINDSTRING function but I can't seem to find what that may be.  Does anyone have any thoughts on how I can get around this issue?

Comment: I think you need to switch places between the expressions, like

FINDSTRING((DT_WSTR,1)[VALUE],".",1) != 0 ? [VALUE] : NULL(DT_R8)

Answer (score 1):

Trying to debug things like this is why I always advocate adding many Derived Columns to the Data Flow. It's impossible to debug that entire expression. Instead, first find the position of the period and add that as a new column. Then you can feed that into the ternary operation and bit by bit you can add data viewers to ensure you are seeing what you expect to see.

Personally, I'd take a different approach. It seems that you'd like to make any columns that are `.` into a null of type DT_R8.

Add a derived column, `TrimmedValue` and use this expression to remove any leading/trailing whitespace and then

```
RTRIM(LTRIM(Value))
```

Add a second derived column component, this time we'll add column `MenopausalValue` as it will remove the period. Use this expression

```
(TrimmmedValue == ".") ? Trimmedvalue : NULL(DT_WSTR, 50)
```

Now, you can add your final Derived Column wherein we convert the string representation of Value to the floating point representation.

```
IsNull(MenopausalValue) ? NULL(DT_R8) : (DT_R8) MenopausalValue
```

If the above shows an error, then you need to apply the following version as I can never remember the evaluation sequence for ternary operations that change type.

```
(DT_R8) (IsNull(MenopausalValue) ? NULL(DT_R8) : (DT_R8) MenopausalValue)
```

Examples of breaking these operations into many steps for debugging purposes

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15176398/181965
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/31123797/181965
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/33023858/181965

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
TRIM(Value) == "." ? NULL(DT_R8) : (DT_R8)Value
```

[image]

[image]